# C# ASP.Net Parameters.AddWithValue rejecting null value for parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I am populating tables using a stored procedure.  The table allows a 'null' for the middle initial of the name, but I'm getting the following error message:

**Procedure or function 'uspInsertPersonalAccountApplication' expects parameter '@MiddleInitial', which was not supplied.**

Thanks in advance!

```
   public void ProcessForm(string[] InputData)
    {
        string ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssociatedBankConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspInsertPersonalAccountApplication", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", "Savings");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountSubType", "Savings");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExistingCustomer","No");
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options here:

Modify you stored procedure and make *@MiddleInitial* param optional (which is currently not optional that's why error is thrown)

```
@MiddleInitial nvarchar(10) = NULL
```

Or add following line to your code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleInitial", null);
```

Comment: I'm passing in 53 paramaters, many of which can be null. How can I dynamically set the DBNull.Value without wrapping each assignment in an IF statement?

Comment: If there is possible to modify stored procedure, then modify paramateres that can be null, and make them optional in stored procedure declaration. That is most flexible solution. If this is not possible you can use `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);` and set `DBNull.Value` for each of them in loop. And then assign the ones you want.

Comment: See comments to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9518215/8479: use `cmd.ParametersAddWithValue("@MiddleInitial", (object)yourVal ?? DBNull.Value);` or add an extension method like `AddParamWithValueOrNull()`

Comment: I tried the AddWithValue("@param", null); which did not work. setting the defaults in the sproc (i.e. @param datetime = null) fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can add to project and use following extension method:

```
public static SqlParameter AddWithValueSafe(this SqlParameterCollection parameters, string parameterName, object value)
{
    return parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, value ?? DBNull.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass in `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.

Comment: I'm passing in 53 paramaters, many of which can be null.  How can I dynamically set the DBNull.Value without wrapping each assignment in an IF statement?

Comment: Add `?? DBNull.Value` after the value, or create a function like `AddValueWithNonNullParameter` that does it for you

Comment: Like this? Intellisense is giving me an error and Intellisense doesn't recognize AddValueWithNullParameter ------- cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleInitial", InputData[11] ?? DBNull.Value);

Comment: Yeah `??` example should work.  If the value before `??` is `null`, it returns the value after `??` instead.  The function AddValueWithNonNullParameter does not exist, you'd have to implement it yourself :)

Comment: Intellisense is saying that: Operator ?? can't be operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'.

Comment: Try `((object) InputData[11]) ?? DBNull.Value` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare on everything - even if it's null.

Use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) for `MiddleInitial`.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleInitial",DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension method to battle this problem.  Marcin's suggestion is also worth considering if you can update the stored procedure.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddString("@MyParamName", myValue);


public static class SQLExtension
{
    public static void AddString(this SqlParameterCollection collection, string parameterName, string value)
    {
        collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, ((object)value) ?? DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the parameter for MiddleInitial also with Null value

```
public void ProcessForm(string[] InputData)
    {
        string ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssociatedBankConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspInsertPersonalAccountApplication", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", "Savings");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountSubType", "Savings");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExistingCustomer","No");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleInitial",DBNull.Value);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you have to set with store procedure

```
@MiddleInitial varhcar(8) = null
```

Comment: +1 This would actually work since the parameter becomes optional